# Configure the WebPart before add it to a page in the SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, addition

I have an issue: gather configuration of the WebPart before add it to a page. For instance, the Silverlight Web Part has the same behaviour. It show modal dialog with asking to enter path to .xap file.

The enviroment is SharePoint Foundation/Server 2010.

I hope that you has already solved this problem. Please share you solution, whever is has been solved or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Web parts properties and configuration are stored in the web parts .dwp file which is just an xml file.

You can manually setup your web part then export the .dwp file via the web part menu. If you examine it in a text editor you will be able to identify the configuration.

You can then import the pre-configured web parts .dwp file using the Add new web part link (can't give you exact instructions as you didn't specify SharePoint 2007 or 2010) or you can import it into the web part gallery so it will be automatically used with "Add new web part"

Comment: Thank you for your answer, very good suggestion. And I need to implement another use case. User press button "Add" (after selection my web part), then I need to show the configuration wizard. In during configuration user can cancel WebPart creation. And last point I think can be solved by you solution. Anyway, thanks a lot!